# Stacking 2 videos horizontal with x264

Tags: video, x264, avisynth

I have two videos of the same length and dimension encoded and I want to combine them into one video in such way, that both videos are viewed next to each other in a single video file. I'm looking for a solution that makes use of the x264 encoder (+ Avisynth script)

Answer (score 0):

Script for this task will be rather simple.

```
first  = DirectShowSource("path_to_the_first_video")
second = DirectShowSource("path_to_the_second_video")
StackHorizontal(first, second)
```

Also there is StackVertical() function.

The avs script is encoded with x264 as usual video, if you have Avisynth installed. Also note that if your Avisynth installation is 32-bit, x264 build also must be 32 bit.

And VirtualDub may be useful for debugging avs scripts to check what you will get before the full encoding.